# How to scroll to next page of pdf in iframe on button click event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, model-view-controller, iframe

I am loading pdf file in an iframe. Now I want to scroll to the next page while I click on the button.
So how can it be possible to move to the next page using a button click event?

```
<div>
    <button id="btnNextPage">Next</button>
</div>
<div>
   <iframe class="frame" id="iframe" src="~/Document/Application.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#btnNextPage").click(function(){
                   //Pdf in iframe should be scrol to next page
           });
     });
</script>
```